# Table/view not found when running jar in ubuntu

Tags: java, eclipse, ubuntu, derby

i try to connect to an embedded derby db using a java program. it works well on windows 10 and when i run it from eclipse in ubuntu but when i run the jar in terminal it throws:

> "java.sql.SQL.SintaxErrorException:Table/View 'REGISTRATION' does not
>   exist."

Do i need to set something in ubuntu to make it work?

```
....................................................
    public class JDBC {
................................................
static Connection conn = null;
    ............................................  
 try{
     Driver derbyEmbeddedDriver = new EmbeddedDriver();
     DriverManager.registerDriver(derbyEmbeddedDriver);
    String dbURL = "jdbc:derby:MyDB;create=true";
    System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);
    System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

 }catch(SQLException se){
    se.printStackTrace();
 }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
 }
................................................................

        JButton btnLogin = new JButton("Login");
     btnLogin.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            try { 
                String query="select * from REGISTRATION where NUME=? and PRENUME=?";
               PreparedStatement pst=conn.prepareStatement(query);
               pst.setString(1, textField.getText());
               pst.setString(2, passwordField.getText());
               ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
               int count=0;
               while(rs.next()){
                   count=count+1;
               }
               if (count == 1 )
               {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Conectat");
                       }
               else 
               {
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Nume sau parola gresite!");
                       }
               rs.close();
               pst.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
                }

            }

    });

    btnLogin.setBounds(25, 182, 117, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnLogin);
.................................................................
```

Comment: The error clearly states that the Table/View called as REGISTRATION does not exist, please create a table called REGISTRATION in derby db on ubuntu.

Comment: Ok you may be able to connect to table REGISTRATION that exists on derbydb located on windows10 machine, but now you are running it in ubuntu which is different from windows, hence create a table REGISTRATION in ubuntu's derbydb.

Comment: The db and table exist and are in  the same folder as the jar. it connects when running the app in eclipse or windows10. the error occurs only when running the jar in terminal  from ubuntu. same jar running from windows10 works fine.

Comment: Do you have all the drivers in place I mean java-derbydb driver in jar?

Comment: the db is the same. is an embedded db so it is not influenced by the operating system. i suspect the problem is that when creating the jar i do not include something specifically for ubuntu. like setting a classpath or something.

Comment: i have the jars for derby in the library. i have the path to the resources set.

Comment: Please show the code with your JDBC Connection URL.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys. I reinstalled ubuntu on my machine and it works. It was some trouble with my operating system.